# Is there any Vedic script where marriage procedure steps are mentioned from end to end?

Tags: marriage, vedic

I wish to understand our Vedic procedure /steps for marriage ceremony.
Is there any Vedic script where marriage procedure steps are mentioned from end to end ?
I have seen people writing article and mention mantras, which are taken from different places and put together. Is there any standard text describing complete marriage ritual  ?